# I'm not sure how to assign the values I want exactly

Tags: c++

I need cherries, oranges, plumes, bells, melons, or bars to be randomly  picked in the case statements and in a way I can then display what was chosen so I can compare them, but I'm not sure how.

For example, I was hoping when I printed slot1, slot2, and slot3, I would get the names of which case statement inside each of the three switches were chosen.

Not their numbers. (The program isn't done yet so it's quite messy right now)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int slot1;
    int slot2;
    int slot3;

    double won;
    double money;

    string cherries;
    string oranges;
    string plums;
    string bells;
    string melons;
    string bars;
    string doAgain;

    do
    {
        cout << "We are going to be playing a slot machine game today." << endl;
        cout << "Please enter the amount of money you'd like to insert into the slot machine." << endl;
        cin >> money;
        cout << "You put in $" << money << endl;


        srand(time(0));

        slot1=rand()%6+1;
        slot2=rand()%6+1;
        slot3=rand()%6+1;

        switch (slot1)
        {
        case 1:
            cout << cherries << endl;
        case 2:
            cout << oranges << endl;
            break;
        case 3:
            cout << plums << endl;
            break;
        case 4:
            cout << bells << endl;
            break;
        case 5:
            cout << melons << endl;
            break;
        case 6:
            cout << bars << endl;
        }

        switch (slot2)
        {
        case 1:
            cout << melons << endl;
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << bells << endl;
            break;
        case 3:
            cout << bars << endl;
            break;
        case 4:
            cout << plums << endl;
            break;
        case 5:
            cout << oranges << endl;
            break;
        case 6:
            cout << cherries << endl;

        }

        switch (slot3)
        {
        case 1:
            cout << bars << endl;
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << plums << endl;
            break;
        case 3:
            cout << melons << endl;
            break;
        case 4:
            cout << bells << endl;
            break;
        case 5:
            cout << oranges << endl;
            break;
        case 6:
            cout << cherries << endl;

        }

       cout << "The numbers you got were " << slot1 << ", " << slot2 << ", " << slot3 << endl;





        cout << "Would you like to play again?" << endl;
        cin >> doAgain;

        if(doAgain!= "yes")
        {
            cout << "The total amount of money you put in the slot machine is" << money << endl;
            cout << "The total amount of money you won is $" << won << endl;
        }

    }
    while(doAgain=="yes");



    return 0;
}

    enter code here
```

Comment: You declared the variable `cherries`, `oranges`, etc., but never assigned anything to them, so they're all empty strings. Why don't you just use literal strings like `cout << "cherries\n";`?

Comment: Can you please put just a little effort into formatting your code to make it more readable? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by readable? : )

Answer (score 1):

1. You have declared strings for all the various fruits, but you don't assign any actual string values to them. ie `string cherries = "cherries"`
2. Just printing slot1 will only print an int as you have discovered. C++ doesn't know that you also want to print the name as well. You need to include your string as part of the cout statement